# LaTeX template for JASIST article

Tags: templates

Does any one have a LaTeX template that can be used to prepare a JASIST manuscript? 
I wrote to the organization and found that they do not have any template for this. However, if there is a template someone has used already, that would be really useful.

Comment: Can you expand JASIST and provide a link? Is this [JASIST](https://www.asis.org/jasist.html)?

Comment: The journal's website mentions that only .rtf and .doc files are accepted. If you insist on writing your document using LaTeX -- an urge I would not wish to discourage! -- you'll need to find a method to convert your tex files into rtf format. There have been several postings regarding just this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting a lot of effort into a template for a journal that does not have a template is most likely not worth while. I assume they accept LaTeX files and so the easiest way for the journal to handle them is if they are as generic as possible. Home made templates may include packages that are or may become outdated or incompatible and may involve home-cooked solutions that are not optimal.

I suggest writing your manuscript in plain LaTeX with the use of as few packages as possible. For references write them in the format of the journal using `\begin-\end{bibliography}` and `\bibitem`. You can of course use BibTeX but then you need to make a style file for the journal.

Answer (score 2):

In response to Mico's comment. There is still  no template but it is now possible to submit using LaTeX. See the quote from their [site](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)2330-1643/homepage/ForAuthors.html)

> Instructions for LaTex submissions:
> Acceptable files formats are: .tex., .bib, .cls, .bst, .sty, as well as .pdf (for review only).
>
> For reviewing purposes you should upload a single .pdf that you have generated from your source files, fonts included, no T3 fonts allowed. The figures and tables should be placed in the manuscript after the paragraph in which they are first mentioned. You must use the File Designation "LaTeX PDF Main Document" from the dropdown box. In addition, you must upload your LaTeX source files. For all your source files you must use the File Designation “Tex/LaTeX Suppl File”.
>
> Images should be uploaded as individual files with “Image” file designation. For acceptable image file formats see “Figures” under the MS Word submission instructions above.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is probably more suited as a comment than an answer.

Comment: @TeXnician I agree, but I don't have 50 rep points to comment